# How can I handle route prefixes?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

I am building an ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2 library, and I am looking for a way to allow any prefix in the route configuration.

I want to add an attribute to a controller, that allows all the following URLs to be passed to the same controller:

```
/some/prefix/MyControllerName/MyAction/ => /MyControllerName/MyAction/
/yet/another/prefix/MyControllerName/MyAction/ => /MyControllerName/MyAction/
/MyControllerName/MyAction/ => (obviously) /MyControllerName/MyAction/
```

I tried a wildcard syntax as such, with no success:

```cs
[Route("*/[controller]/[action]")]
public abstract class MyBaseController : Controller { }
```

In other words, I would like to have the beginning of the path (before the actual controller name) totally ignored.

Comment: *Any* prefix, or multiple pre-defined prefixes?

Comment: Any prefix.....

Comment: Could this be an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @UweKeim Yeah, I was just thinking the same thing. What's the actual use case here? When would an action be used where the prefix is not already known?

Comment: The X of my Y question is, since I'm building a generic library, to let freedom for the url prefix, if any, when implementing concrete controller, or even allowing the prefix to be weakly set through url calls.

Comment: Another X would be to define a hard coded scheme at abstract controller level (like /prefix/controller/action), and allow / force override in the concrete controller.

Comment: Sounds like a bad idea to me (aka "premature optimization"). Better build build a precise library and if you use it the 2nd time, _then_ generalize it.

Comment: I'm way beyond the second time of usage, and my current implementations are duplicating code (either configuring all prexies in the UseMvc() middleware, or repeating the scheme in controllers attributes).

Comment: You can already create custom prefixes for an application by using virtual directories, which doesn't affect the prefixes you use. (i.e. you can put the whole application under `/Something/SomethingElse` - the prefix you use in the application would still be `/Controller/Action` but accessible at `/Something/SomethingElse/Controller/Action`)

Comment: Virtual directories are at implementation time or even at runtime, but shouldn't be defined at library level. I would like to allow any-or-no route scheme prefix in the abstract controller, so that all the concrete controllers can override/implement prefix

Comment: I missed that it was abstract. But that just confirms that you don't need to worry about this. Anyone using your abstract controller can apply their own `[Route]` to their derived controller, which will override the one you defined.

Comment: Even if you could apply a wildcard prefix, that would break the use of any method that needs to construct the route for an action (like `Url.Action`) because the prefix is unknown now.

Comment: Applying `[Route]` in derived is what I am currently doing (and of course it is working). So it there is no way to generalize the scheme in the abstract controller, I'll leave it as it is.